# Can Java JSSC library detect a lost connection?

Tags: java, jssc

I know serial ports are not so good but still a little hope... I am using JSSC library for communication.

Does the JSSC library have a method to detect when an established connection is lost due to hardware removal?

Comment: I've used this library but can't remember anymore...Maybe you could check if there is an exception when you try to read or write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jssc does not have hot plug or device removal like mechanism. Give details of your hardware and we may think of some work around.

Comment: It is a serial port of Micro-controller of MC9S12G Family (freescale) with computer.

Comment: You may use GPIO or DTR for hotpulg. The uC will keep for example DTR always high and that is read by PC.

Comment: Unfortunaltely DTR and DSR are not implemented in hardware. its just 4 wire communication RX,TX,VCC and GND

Comment: Then the only option is like watchdog. PC application sends some data periodically and uC replies. If the uC fails to reply this means it is unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is set a suitable (for your case) timeout on the read and when you get the timeout exception you close the port and keep trying to open it again till you succeed:

```
            serial.setReadTimeout(10000);
            
            while (1 == 1) {

                try {

                    System.out.print((char) serial.read());

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    System.out.println("lost connection?");

                    serial.close();

                    while (!serial.isOpened()) {
                        
                        try {

                            serial.open();
                            
                        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                            
                            // keep trying...
                        }
                    }
                        
                    System.out.println("reopened");
                }
            }
```