# Serial Port insertion/removal detection jssc library

Tags: java, jssc

How to detect removal or insertion of serial port during normal operation? I am using jssc library in my Java Swing application.

I know about the exception part but it is not working according to the condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Java JSSC library detect a lost connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629180/can-java-jssc-library-detect-a-lost-connection)

Comment: it's not the duplicate of that post first of all . My approach is different from that ...  I am not depending on any uC to reply back . i am only asking from the jSSC side ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking, but the accepted answer to the referenced question was suggesting a workaround that involved the uC because, "_jssc does not have hot plug or device removal like mechanism_"

Comment: Okay! .... Thanks alot for you time :) .. then i have to change my approach ... thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already mentioned this in the comments, but I'll add an answer for anyone else who might stumble across this question in the future.

According to the accepted answer for ['Can Java JSSC library detect a lost connection?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629180/can-java-jssc-library-detect-a-lost-connection)

> The jssc does not have hot plug or device removal like mechanism

Comment: thanks alot for your advice . however , now i am  using different strategy as to set "timeouts" for serialport as if with in a specified amount of time it doesn't read data then it should trigger an popup error. So, will this approach be useful ?